# Extract cue-point or data from live video stream

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer

Does anybody know of a way I can extract timing data from any kind of live video stream?

I have tried with JWPlayer, but it is not capable of doing that.
My encoder is Streamcoders Mediasuite and I am happy to stream using whatever streamtype is necessary, in order for me to get cuepoint info (or any kind of timing info) from the stream.

Caveat - Flash and Silverlight are not an option, as the viewer-base is restricted by policy.

Thanks in advance.

Neil.

Comment: Ideally, I need to get segment timestamps from the live stream. We have an application which  synchronises slides to display on-screen, alongside the video.  As the timestamp is retrieved from the stream, the front-end will then display the correct slide.
The end-users are no longer able to have Silverlight or Flash, so we have to find a different way to get the timing info for the slide display.

Due to buffering and latency, this timestamp must come from the stream itself, and can't be sent from the encoder through a web service.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would the use of stream metadata coupled with the jwplayer().on("meta", ...) listener work?

Comment: Hi @jherrieven.
I ma looking into that, although jwplayer's on('meta') does not seem to be able to see the meta data alresady included in a stream. Using Chrome's media-internals, I can see a timestamp, but am unable to retrieve it using javascript.  It must be meta-data, as it is not video content, but I cannot read it.

Comment: Ok. I am getting some form of time from event.metadata.segment.mediaSequenceNumber.
If I set my chunk duration to 1000ms at the Wowza end, this might help.  However, it is not ideal, as it doesn't distinguish between a holding loop and live stream.

Comment: Do you have an example stream I could take a look at?